# loading content from php file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code fetch all data (by clicking a.info link) from a php file "info.php" and prints in the #content div. The problem is that it prints everything from info.php file. Can I possibly select only some part of data from info.php file to load in #content?
The reason to ask this question is that, I want to load different data from the same php file for the different links.

```
$("a.info").click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr("id");
$("#box").slideDown("slow");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "id="+$(this).attr("id"),
    url: "info.php",
    success: function(html){
        $("#content").html(html);
    } 
});
});
```

**Html where content is loading:**

```
   <div id="box">
    <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
```

**info.php**

```
paragraph1.
    paragraph2.
```

For example, In the above info.php file, i only want to load paragraph1 in the #content.
    I hope my question is clear. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can control the ouput in info.php (which mean ouput paragaph1 only) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `paragraph1` is a div element, change accordingly:

```
success: function(html){
    var p1 = $(html).find("div#paragraph1");
    $("#content").html(p1);
}
```